# Javascript - Adding multiple keys with same value from FOR loop into empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am new to stackoverflow so I am sorry if this question has been answered, what did  find just led to more confusion. Been at this for hours.

My issue is when I try to add multiple keys with the same value, I only get the last key and value to store inside of the object. I used if/else statements to try and achieve my goal. Here is my code.

```
var itemData = [{
    category: 'fruit',
    itemName: 'apple',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'beans',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'corn',
    onSale: true
  },
  {
    category: 'frozen',
    itemName: 'pizza',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'fruit',
    itemName: 'melon',
    onSale: true
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'soup',
    onSale: false
  },
];

let list = {  }


for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  
if (items[i].category === 'fruit' && items[i].onSale === false) { 
       Object.assign(list, {fruit : [`${items[i].itemName}`]})  
       
   }
  else if (items[i].category === 'fruit' && items[i].onSale === true) { 
     list.fruit.push(`${items[i].itemName}${'($)'}`)
   
   }
else if (items[i].category === 'canned' && items[i].onSale === false) {

Object.assign(list, {canned : [`${items[i].itemName}`,] })  
    list.canned.push(`${items[i].itemName}`)
  }
  
}
```

console.log(list) shows

```
{
  canned: ["soup", "soup"],
  fruit: ["apple", "melon($)"]
}
```

but im expecting

```
{
  canned: ["beans", "soup"],
  fruit: ["apple", "melon($)"]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`` Object.assign(list, {canned : [`${items[i].itemName}`,] }) ``  in your last else if statement overwrites the existing list  `canned` in the second loop iteration.

The easiest solution is to add `cannes` right at the beginning when your create `list`

```
let list = {cannes: []}
```

Then you can drop the `Object.assign` line completely.

For `fruit` you should do the same and replace the `Object.assign` line with `list.fruit.push()`

If you only want to create `cannes` if any item is found which meets your condition, just add a if/else statement which checks if `cannes` exists or not.

```
if ( ! 'canned' in list )
    Object.assign(list, {canned : [`${items[i].itemName}`,] })
else
    list.canned.push(`${items[i].itemName}`)
```

Comment: Thank you, your method worked. But I was hoping I could accomplish this task without first adding the key and value placeholder.  Im wondering if there is any way to do it. But thanks again for your help!

Comment: @praxeaze Sure, you just have to add a if statement which checks if ```cannes``` exists or not and create it if it does not exists. Like
```if ( ! 'canned' in list) Object.assign(list, {canned : [`${items[i].itemName}`,] })
else list.canned.push(`${items[i].itemName}`)```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var itemData = [{
    category: 'fruit',
    itemName: 'apple',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'beans',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'corn',
    onSale: true
  },
  {
    category: 'frozen',
    itemName: 'pizza',
    onSale: false
  },
  {
    category: 'fruit',
    itemName: 'melon',
    onSale: true
  },
  {
    category: 'canned',
    itemName: 'soup',
    onSale: false
  },
];

let list = {};
let counter = 0;


itemData.forEach(isOnSale);
console.log(list);

function isOnSale(item) {
  

    if (item['onSale'] === false && item['category'] === 'canned') {

      //Initially Creating array and then pushing items 
      if (counter > 0) {
        list['canned'].push(item['itemName'])
      } else {
        list['canned'] = Array(item['itemName'])
      }

          
      counter++;

    } else if (item['category'] === 'fruit') {
    
    if (counter > 0) {
        (item['onSale'] === false) ? list['fruit'].push(item['itemName']): list['fruit'].push(`${item['itemName'].concat('($)')}`);
      } else {
        list['fruit'] = (item['onSale'] === false) ? Array(item['itemName']) : Array (`${item['itemName'].concat('($)')}`);
      }
    }

}
```